# PHP Search pipe delimited text file for 3 variables

Tags: php, string, search, csv

I have some script shown below. It searches for 2 variables and outputs the entire line if both variables are found. I need to include a third variable then output just the first delimited variable in the line. The delimiter is a pipe (|). Any help gratefully received. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php 
$variable1 = $_REQUEST["variable1"]; 
$variable2 = $_REQUEST['variable2'];
// Read from file 
$lines = file('results.txt'); 
echo"<html><head><title>SEARCH RESULTS FOR: $variable1 and $variable2</title></head><body>";
foreach($lines as $line) 
{ 
// Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does 
if(stristr($line,$variable1) && stristr($line,$variable2)) // case insensitive
echo "<font face='Arial'> $line </font><hr>"; 
} 
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You can explode to easily get the first variable: `explode('|',$line);`, but I would popen grep and sed. Assuming you are not on a Linux box, you can fopen the file and process each line with fgetcsv to get the variables as an array - which will handle escaped delimiters for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't really know how to do that...